# почему компилятор musl-gcc не видит директорию в операционной системе

Tags: linux, gcc

Запускаю сборку но почему-то не видит директорию (может быть какую ни буть директорию либо библиотеку не подключил ).

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/c11_mnogopotok$ musl-gcc -I/usr/include/GLFW/ -I/usr/include/GL/ -I/usr/inb/x86_64-linux-gnu/ main.c -o tream1 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw -lOpenGL -lGLEW
In file included from main.c:6:0:
/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:171:12: fatal error: GL/gl.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
   #include <GL/gl.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

вот подключения заголовочных файлов в **main.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <threads.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <glfw3.h>
```

вот директория в операционной системе :

```
comp@comp0:/usr/include/GL$ ls
freeglut_ext.h  glew.h       glu.h         glxext.h      glxmd.h      wglew.h
freeglut.h      glext.h      glu_mangle.h  glx.h         glxproto.h
freeglut_std.h  gl.h         glut.h        glxint.h      glxtokens.h
glcorearb.h     gl_mangle.h  glxew.h       glx_mangle.h  internal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

понял в чём проблема

Надо было добавить директорию  `-I/usr/include/` .

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/c11_mnogopotok$ musl-gcc -I/usr/include/GLFW/ -I/usr/include/GL/ -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/inb/x86_64-linux-gnu/ main.c -o tream1 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw -lOpenGL -lGLEW
In file included from main.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Правда теперь иная ошибка ну по крайней мере смог продвинуться :3